Windows 11 answers to arp-scan while in sleep mode
I use apr-scan to identify devices connected to my home network (from a notebook running Ubuntu 22.04 and a Raspberry Pi running Raspberry Pi OS 12). There is a single notbook running Windows 11 in my network. When it is running, it answers to arp-scan and ping as I would expect. However, when it is in sleep mode, it still answers to arp-scan, while it does not answer to ping. This means that arp-scan alone cannot tell me, whether this computer is currently active.
There are several Ubuntu machines in the network and all of them do not respond to arp-scan and ping when in sleep mode. I expected the Windows device to show the same behaviour, but this is not the case.
I have already tried to deactivate "Wake on LAN" on the Windows PC by following the first two steps in this manual (which is unfortunately in German): I disabled "Wake on LAN" in the BIOS and I disabled "Wake on Magic Packet" for the network adapter in the device manager. This has not changed anything.
So, I have two closely related questions:

Is this the expected behaviour, that is, should Windows 11 reply to arp-scan when in sleep mode?
If so, is there anything I can do to change this behaviour, that is, can I make Windows not reply to arp-scan when in sleep mode?


You might experiment with USB suspend (on some laptops, NIC is USB-connected) and Wireless Adapter setting in Power Options to see if that helps.

@DrMoishePippik Thanks for this excellent idea. I indeed found a setting in the Power Options that controls what happens with the network when in sleep mode (actually, I had to first enable this option as described here). Unfortunately, it has no effect: arp-scan still lists to Windows machine when it is in sleep.
